# Nodejs express error upload file debian vps

Tags: node.js, linux, multer

I'm trying to upload file to nodejs server.
I use multer.

```
const multer  = require('multer'); const UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads'; 
const upload = multer({ dest: `${UPLOAD_PATH}/` }); 
const sericesApi=(app)=> {
     app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
         try {
             res.send({'file':req.file});
         } catch (err) {
             res.sendStatus(400);
         }
    }); }
module.exports = sericesApi;
```

On my localhost(Ubuntu 16.04) all is good, but on VPS -  Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie) I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED or ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
I've tried to use: multer, busboy, express-fileupload. All didn't work

Comment: Both errors sound like they are related to networking issues (like a firewall that's blocking incoming requests), not to your server code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! It was problem with pm2 with watch parameter. It restarted app after upload new file